# Random CFNetwork SSLHandshake failed (-9806) on ios 8 with invalid ssl certificates

Tags: ios8

I am getting  CFNetwork SSLHandshake failed (-9806) error on ios 8.
Same code works fine on ios 7 but fails on ios 8 randomly.

Comment: Same. Don't really know what to do with it. Btw, I don't use any network framework, just NSURLConnection.

Comment: Do you use in Settings->Developer->Network Link Conditioner? It's so rare and random, so it's really hard to understand what cause it.

Comment: Did you find the solution?